# Yii, CActiveDataProvider, и произвольный sql

Tags: php, yii, sql

Есть некий sql запрос

```
select 
    t1.id,
    (
        select 
            count(t2.parent_id) 
        from 
            om2_partner t2 
        where 
            t1.id=t2.parent_id 
        group by 
            t2.parent_id
    ) as count_ref
from 
    om2_partner t1
```

Никак не получается собрать его через `criteria`. Может, имеется возможность как-то исполнить произвольный `sql`. Просто это все очень топорно и ограничено.

Comment: > Может, имеется возможность как-то исполнить произвольный sql

Можно попробовать засунуть весь вложенный селект в `CDbExpression`, правда это будет ужасно выглядеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```

[полный перечень свойств и методов CDbCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand)

Для этого слегка перепишем запрос

```
SELECT t.id, count(t2.id) as count_ref FROM om2_partner t
LEFT JOIN om2_partner t2 ON t.id=t2.periods
GROUP BY t2.id
```

Оговорюсь, алиас, конечно, можно изменить, но в Yii по дефолту алиас таблицы текущей модели записывается, как t

А если нужно именно через `CDbCriteria`

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 't.id, count(t2.id) as count_ref';
$criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN om2_partner t2 ON t.id=t2.periods '
$criteria->group = 't2.id'
```

И в модели нужно завести public свойство `count_ref` (если его нет), иначе будет ругаться, что такого свойства в классе не существует.